# Can't locate an element overlayed Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrap some data from : https://parisportif.pmu.fr/home/wrapper/dashboard?lang=fr&activeSportId=1. But I got a cookies overlay which I can't locate and click on a button. Ctrl+U does not show the element but the js script that show the element.

I tried this :

```
driver.get('https://parisportif.pmu.fr/home/wrapper/dashboard?lang=fr&activeSportId=1')
time.sleep(5)
jaccepte = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Tout accepter")]')
jaccepte.click()
```

and all sort of `WebDriverWait`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an **iframe** Tag.
First of all you have to get iframe element.

```
frame = driver.find_element('xpath','//iframe')
```

Then, you have to **switch** on iframe.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

After this you can access that button and click on it.
for backing on the **default** and first frame you can use

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```